# add a bit of text from one column, into new column?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is it possible to add the IP address from the column "Connectionstring", to the column "IP_Adress", just with the use of a SQL Query?
The query should do it on all the rows, regardless of the length of the IP address.
[image: Updated Image.]

Comment: Post your table structure and a data set

Comment: Yes, it's possible.

Comment: How you want to update the IP_Address column? After inserting the record in row before inserting record of anything else?

Comment: The Image is updated now.

Comment: Do you want an additional column to your result set, or to the table?

Comment: I just want to extract the IP address from the "Connectionstring"-column, and put that seperately to the IP_Address-column, for all the rows. =)

Comment: Are all of your connection strings in the same format?  If not; how many different formats are there?  Can you provide (text) samples of each?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can like below:

```
DECLARE @Tmp VARCHAR(50) = 'Data Source=10.16.190.2;Initial Catalog'
SELECT REPLACE(LEFT(@Tmp, CHARINDEX(';Initial', @Tmp, 0) - 1), 'Data Source=', '') -- 10.16.190.2
```

Usage:

```
UPDATE Laeger
SET IP_Adresse = REPLACE(LEFT(Connectionstring, CHARINDEX(';Initial', Connectionstring, 0) - 1), 'Data Source=', '')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot mate.. that did what i wanted.

Comment: Sure, but it didnt work well with another bit i wanted to extract from the column. So i used the answer from Ullas, at the buttom =)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do the job for you

```
UPDATE *TABLENAME*
   SET IP_ADDRESS = SUBSTRING(CONNECTRIONSTRING, 13, (CHARINDEX(CONNECTRIONSTRIONG, ';', 13) - 13)
```

Answer (score 0):

If the `DataSource` part is always at the start. Then you can achieve this with a combination of `SUBSTRING` and `CHARINDEX`.

**Query**

```
UPDATE [your_table_name]
SET [IP_Address] = SUBSTRING(
                   [connectionstring], 
                   CHARINDEX('=', [connectionstring], 1) + 1, 
                   CHARINDEX(';', [connectionstring], 1) - 
                      CHARINDEX('=', [connectionstring], 1) - 1);
```

Else

You can use a combination of `PATINDEX`, `RIGHT`, `LEFT` and `CHARINDEX`.
As I know `DataSource` part can be anywhere in the connection string.

So find the position of the word `DataSource=` from the entire string using `PATINDEX` do the functions according to that.

**Query**

```
SELECT 
REPLACE((
LEFT(
RIGHT([connectionstring], LEN([connectionstring]) - 
                 PATINDEX('%Data Source=%', [connectionstring]) + 1),
             CHARINDEX(';', 
             RIGHT([connectionstring], LEN([connectionstring]) - 
             PATINDEX('%Data Source=%', [connectionstring]) + 1)) - 1)), 
      'Data Source=', '') AS [IP_Adress]
FROM [your_table_name];
```

And if you want to update,

```
UPDATE [your_table_name]
SET [IP_Address] = REPLACE((
LEFT(
RIGHT([connectionstring], LEN([connectionstring]) - 
      PATINDEX('%Data Source=%', connectionstring) + 1),
CHARINDEX(';', 
 RIGHT([connectionstring], LEN([connectionstring]) - 
       PATINDEX('%Data Source=%', [connectionstring]) + 1)) - 1)), 
      'Data Source=', '');
```

Comment: It says that i need to declare the @conn.. What is that supposed to be?

Comment: @MichaelEjvindTherkildsen : Its just a string variable of mine when i tested it out. You can change it to your column name. And my answer has been updated.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Just what i wanted. With this i can replace the strings to copy some other stuff from the column, to a specifik column =)

Answer (score 0):

Use the next Code via using [substring](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187748.aspx) & [charindex](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186323.aspx) functions.

```
update laeger
set IP_Address = substring(connectionstring, 
                charindex('=' , connectionstring) + 1 , 
                charindex(';', connectionstring) - charindex('=' , connectionstring) - 1)
```

**Demo:-**

```
Create table laeger (connectionstring nvarchar(2000) , IP_Address nvarchar(50))
go
insert into laeger (connectionstring) values ('DataSource = 10.10.12.114;aaaaaaaaa')
insert into laeger (connectionstring) values ('DataSource = 10.12.2.5;bbbbbbbb')
insert into laeger (connectionstring) values ('DataSource = 10.10.121.114;cccccccccc')
insert into laeger (connectionstring) values ('DataSource = 10.10.1.1;dddddddd')
insert into laeger (connectionstring) values ('DataSource = 10.10.12.8;eeeeeeeeee')
go
select * from laeger
```

**Result:-**

[image]

```
update laeger
set IP_Address = substring(connectionstring, 
                charindex('=' , connectionstring) + 1 , 
                charindex(';', connectionstring) - charindex('=' , connectionstring) - 1)
go              
select * from laeger
```

**Result after updating:-**

[image]